Async SQLAlchemy and pytest Error: AsyncConnection context has not been started and object has not been awaited
How to configure AsyncEngine and AsyncSession of SQLAlchemy for pytest?
I'm using FastAPI framework to build and develop the APIs for the project I'm working on with SQLAlchemy, SQLModel and PostgreSQL.
Here I'm sharing the whole error log printed by pytest:
―――――――――――――――――――― ERROR at setup of test_get_favourites ――――――――――――――――――――

request = <SubRequest 'engine' for <Coroutine test_get_favourites>>
kwargs = {'monkeysession': <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f09ac5caf00>}, func = <function engine_mock at 0x7f09ac346660>
event_loop_fixture_id = '_session_event_loop'
setup = <function _wrap_asyncgen_fixture.<locals>._asyncgen_fixture_wrapper.<locals>.setup at 0x7f09ac2ecd60>
finalizer = <function _wrap_asyncgen_fixture.<locals>._asyncgen_fixture_wrapper.<locals>.finalizer at 0x7f09ac2ec900>

    @functools.wraps(fixture)
    def _asyncgen_fixture_wrapper(request: FixtureRequest, **kwargs: Any):
        func = _perhaps_rebind_fixture_func(fixture, request.instance)
        event_loop_fixture_id = _get_event_loop_fixture_id_for_async_fixture(
            request, func
        )
        event_loop = request.getfixturevalue(event_loop_fixture_id)
        kwargs.pop(event_loop_fixture_id, None)
        gen_obj = func(**_add_kwargs(func, kwargs, event_loop, request))

        async def setup():
            res = await gen_obj.__anext__()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
            return res

        def finalizer() -> None:
            """Yield again, to finalize."""

            async def async_finalizer() -> None:
                try:
                    await gen_obj.__anext__()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
                except StopAsyncIteration:
                    pass
                else:
                    msg = "Async generator fixture didn't stop."
                    msg += "Yield only once."
                    raise ValueError(msg)

            event_loop.run_until_complete(async_finalizer())

>       result = event_loop.run_until_complete(setup())

../local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytest_asyncio/plugin.py:343:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
../local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py:686: in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
../local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytest_asyncio/plugin.py:325: in setup
    res = await gen_obj.__anext__()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
tests/conftest.py:36: in engine_mock
    async with await test_engine_tmp.connect().execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT") as conn:
../local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py:439: in execution_options
    conn = self._proxied
../local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:1130: in __get__
    return self.fget(obj)
../local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py:325: in _proxied
    self._raise_for_not_started()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.engine.AsyncConnection object at 0x7f09ac2d0af0>

    def _raise_for_not_started(self) -> NoReturn:
>       raise async_exc.AsyncContextNotStarted(
            "%s context has not been started and object has not been awaited."
            % (self.__class__.__name__)
        )
E       sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.exc.AsyncContextNotStarted: AsyncConnection context has not been started and object has not been awaited.

../local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/base.py:130: AsyncContextNotStarted
                                                                                                                                 100% ██████████
=========================================================== short test summary info ============================================================
FAILED tests/unit_tests/test_favourite.py::test_get_favourites - sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.exc.AsyncContextNotStarted: AsyncConnection context has not been started and object has not been awaited.

Due to less expertise in async programming I started the DB configuration with blocking one (sync config), then I realized that for better performance with FastAPI I should use async sqlalchemy.
So, I reconfigured all the settings and configs to as below:
Installed asyncpg and modified the DB URL accordingly:
FROM: postgresql+psycopg://user:password@db:5432/search_db?options=-csearch_path=search_schema,public
TO: postgresql+asyncpg://user:password@db:5432/search_db
and modified the db configuration module accordingly:
# dkm_commons.db_session.py

from collections.abc import AsyncGenerator
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends
import orjson
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlmodel import MetaData as SmMetaData
from sqlmodel.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession

from .config import settings

model_meta = SmMetaData(schema=settings.POSTGRES_SCHEMA)


class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    metadata = MetaData(schema=settings.POSTGRES_SCHEMA)


def orjson_serializer(obj):
    """
    Note that `orjson.dumps()` return byte array, while sqlalchemy expects string, thus `decode()` call.
    This function helped to solve JSON datetime conversion issue on JSONB column
    """
    return orjson.dumps(obj, option=orjson.OPT_SERIALIZE_NUMPY | orjson.OPT_NAIVE_UTC).decode()


engine = create_async_engine(
    str(settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI),
    # required for sqlite
    json_serializer=orjson_serializer,
    json_deserializer=orjson.loads,
    connect_args={},
    echo=settings.ENVIRONMENT == "local",
    future=True,
    pool_size=20,
    max_overflow=30,
)

async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)


async def get_session() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session


SessionDep = Annotated[AsyncSession, Depends(get_session)]


Then the conftest.py for pytest.
In this I'm creating a new test database always for testing purposes then dropping at the end:

Creating a test db with random name
Creating all the tables and pg extensions required
Dropping the test db at the end

# conftest.py

from collections.abc import AsyncGenerator
import secrets

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from httpx import AsyncClient
from loguru import logger
import orjson
import pytest
import pytest_asyncio
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.exc import DBAPIError, OperationalError, ProgrammingError
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
from sqlmodel.ext.asyncio.session import AsyncSession

from dkm_commons.db_session import Base, get_session, model_meta, orjson_serializer

from app.core.config import settings
from app.main import app
from tests.factories.user import login_data


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def monkeysession():
    with pytest.MonkeyPatch.context() as mp:
        yield mp


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(name="engine", scope="session", autouse=True)
async def engine_mock(monkeysession: pytest.MonkeyPatch) -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncEngine, None]:
    db_url = str(settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI).split("?")[0]
    db_name = f"test_db_{settings.POSTGRES_DB.get_secret_value()}_{secrets.token_hex(8)}"
    test_engine_tmp = create_async_engine(db_url, poolclass=NullPool)
    try:
        async with await test_engine_tmp.connect().execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT") as conn:
            # async with test_engine_tmp.connect() as conn:
            await conn.execute(text(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name}"))
            await conn.commit()
            logger.info(f"Test DB {db_name} created!")
    except (ProgrammingError, OperationalError, DBAPIError) as err:
        logger.error(f"Could not create the database {db_name}, probably already exist.")
        logger.error(err)
    finally:
        await test_engine_tmp.dispose()

    parts = db_url.split("/")
    parts[-1] = db_name
    test_engine = create_async_engine(
        "/".join(parts),
        poolclass=NullPool,
        json_serializer=orjson_serializer,
        json_deserializer=orjson.loads,
        connect_args={},
        future=True,
    )
    try:
        async with await test_engine.connect().execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT") as conn:
            schema_name = settings.POSTGRES_SCHEMA
            await conn.execute(text("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS vector;"))
            await conn.execute(text('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";'))
            await conn.execute(text(f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {schema_name};"))
            await conn.execute(text(f"SET search_path='{schema_name}';"))
    except (ProgrammingError, OperationalError, DBAPIError) as err:
        logger.error("Cannot create extensions.")
        logger.error(err)

    async with test_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
        await conn.run_sync(model_meta.create_all)

    monkeysession.setattr("dkm_commons.db_session.engine", test_engine)

    yield test_engine

    await test_engine.dispose()

    try:
        async with await test_engine_tmp.connect().execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT") as conn:
            await conn.execute(text(f"DROP DATABASE {db_name}"))
            logger.info(f"Test DB {db_name} dropped!")
    except (ProgrammingError, OperationalError, DBAPIError) as err:
        logger.error(f"Could not drop the database {db_name}!")
        logger.error(err)
    finally:
        await test_engine_tmp.dispose()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(name="session")
async def session_fixture(engine: AsyncEngine) -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(name="client")
async def client_fixture(session: AsyncSession, monkeysession: pytest.MonkeyPatch) -> AsyncGenerator[TestClient, None]:
    def get_session_override():
        return session

    monkeysession.setattr("dkm_commons.db_session.get_session", get_session_override)
    app.dependency_overrides[get_session] = get_session_override
    yield TestClient(app)
    app.dependency_overrides.clear()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(name="auth_client")
async def test_auth_client(client: TestClient) -> AsyncGenerator[TestClient, None]:
    client.headers["x-apim-token-user-id"] = str(login_data.id)
    yield client


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(name="async_auth_client")
async def async_auth_client_fixture() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncClient, None]:
    client = AsyncClient(app=app)  # type:ignore[call-arg]
    client.headers["x-apim-token-user-id"] = str(login_data.id)
    yield client


